# Why does spark-shell not start SQL context?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7 and am setting up a Spark environment.  I have completed most of the steps to install and configure, but finally, I found something different from the online tutorials.

[image: Screenshot]

The logs are missing the line:

> SQL context available as sqlContext.

When I run spark-shell, it just starts the Spark context. Why is the SQL context not started?

Under normal circumstances, should the following two lines of code be run at the same time?

```
Spark context available as sc
SQL context available as sqlContext.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Spark 2.0 onwards [SparkSession](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html) is used instead (as SQL Context/`sqlContext` was "renamed" to `SparkSession`/`spark`).

When you run spark-shell, you will get a reference to this spark session as `spark`. You should see the following:

> Spark session available as 'spark'.

If you want to access the underlying SQL context you could do the following:

```
spark.sqlContext
```

Please don't since it's no longer required and most operations can be executed without it.